# What does this random variable represent?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

For some strictly positive b and function $h(x)$ such that $0 \le h(x) \le b$ whenever $0 \le x \le 1$, and two standard uniform random variables ${U_1},{U_2}$ we define a new random variable as $X = 1,{\rm{ whenever}}b{U_2} < h\left( {{U_1}} \right)$ and zero otherwise. I am having difficulty visualising what X's pmf will look like.

Comment: Note that $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable because it can only take values of $0$ or $1$.  It does not have a PDF, so that is why you are having trouble "visualizing" its PDF. It has a PMF and you only need to calculate $P[X=1]$.

Comment: Note that $bU_2$ is uniform over $[0,b]$, and also $h(U_1) \in [0,b]$.  So intuitively you want the probability that the value obtained by evaluating $h(\cdot)$ at a randomly chosen point is larger than an (independently drawn?) variable that is uniform over $[0,b]$. [Actually, now I notice that $U_1,U_2$ are not stated as being independent. So that is an ambiguity in the question.]

Comment: Ah yes, the "PDF" was a typo, meant to write PMF. The uniform variables are indeed independent. What I was aiming to do, was to use X to estimate $\int\limits_0^1 {h(x)dx} $. For which $h(U_1)$ is understood to be a Monte Carlo Estimator. How would one calculate the probability?

Comment: I discourage you from jumping to conclusions about the structure of the answer, particularly if that structure is "close" to being correct, as it may reinforce bad methodology.  You have to compute $P[bU_2 < h(U_1)]$.  This event involves two independent random variables, you have "the law of total probability" (in integral form) that allows you to condition on the value of one of those variables, and this will make the problem easy.  In general if $A$ is an event and $Z$ is a random variable with PDF $f_Z(z)$ then $$P[A] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P[A|Z=z]f_Z(z)dz$$

Comment: That is really helpful. By the law of total probability then I would have that $\Pr \left( {{U_2} \le \frac{{h\left( {{U_1}} \right)}}{b}} \right) = \int\limits_0^1 {\Pr \left( {{U_2} \le \frac{{h\left( u \right)}}{b}} \right) \cdot 1du}  = \frac{1}{b}\int\limits_0^1 {h(u)du} $ This would imply that bZ has the expectation that I want from it.